# Metrix package: draw the bow above the syllable instead of below

Tags: tikz-pgf, metrix

This is all in the title: I want a `\bow` command which displays the bow above the syllable, as on those pages:

[image]

In case someone else than @Tobi wants to give a try, the definition of `\bow` as indicated in the documentation of the `metrix` package is the following (Copyright `Tobias Weh`):

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \bow } { O{0pt} m O{0pt} }
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
baseline = (l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int.base),
every~metrix~bow
]
\node [every~metrix~syllable~node]
(l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int)
{ #2 };
\draw [shorten~< = #1, shorten~> = #3]
($(l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int.base~west)+
(\usemetrixvar{bowshortening},\usemetrixvar{bowshift})$)
to [out=-45, in=225,looseness=\usemetrixvar{bowlooseness}]
($(l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int.base~east)+
(-\usemetrixvar{bowshortening},\usemetrixvar{bowshift})$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{metrix}



\begin{document}

\metrics{ _ u u _ | _ _ | _ | _ u u _ | _ _ }
{flos ve-te-ris | vi-ni | \bow{meis} | na-ri-bus ob{-} | {-}iec-tust}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version with `out=-45, in=225` reversed, i.e., `out=45, in=-225`, to mirror the bow horizontally. Then the vertical position can be adjusted (globally) with `\setmetrixvar{bowshift}{1.5ex}`. Does look a bit cramped though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{metrix}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \topbow } { O{0pt} m O{0pt} }
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
baseline = (l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int.base),
every~metrix~bow
]
\node [every~metrix~syllable~node]
(l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int)
{ #2 };
\draw [shorten~< = #1, shorten~> = #3]
($(l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int.base~west)+
(\usemetrixvar{bowshortening},\usemetrixvar{bowshift})$)
to [out=45, in=-225,looseness=\usemetrixvar{bowlooseness}]
($(l__metrix_syllable_node_\int_use:N \l__metrix_process_int.base~east)+
(-\usemetrixvar{bowshortening},\usemetrixvar{bowshift})$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setmetrixvar{bowshift}{1.5ex}
\metrics{ _ u u _ | _ _ | _ | _ u u _ | _ _ }
{flos ve-te-ris | vi-ni | \topbow{meis} | na-ri-bus ob{-} | {-}iec-tust}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to raise the symbols a little, e.g. `\setmetrixvar{symbolshift}{2.7ex}`